# Ограничения лицензии продукта PostgreSQL от EnterpriseDB

Tags: postgresql, лицензирование

Необходимо прояснить ситуацию с лицензией продукта PostgreSQL, загруженной с этой страницы http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

У меня несколько вопросов:

1. Возможно ли, не нарушая лицензию, поставлять дистрибутив PostgreSQL на одном оптическом накопителе вместе с дистрибутивом коммерческого продукта, разрабатываемого с использованием сервера PostgreSQL?
2. Разрешается ли запускать инсталлятор PostgreSQL через .bat файл, передающий параметры инсталлятору, не нарушая лицензию?
3. Если по 1-ому вопросу ответ положителен, то как правильно следует оформить copyright, readme?

Буду очень благодарен за подробные ответы, с указанием на места в лицензионном договоре (извините, но в английском не силен и не юрист, а ситуация требует ясного ответа без вольного перевода)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [FAQ](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/faq/):

> **Q: How is PostgreSQL licensed? How much does it cost?**
>   A: PostgreSQL is released under the OSI-approved PostgreSQL License. There is no fee, even for use in commercial software products. Please see the [PostgreSQL License](https://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/)

> **В: Какая на PostgreSQL лицензия? Сколько он стоит?**
>   О: PostgreSQL выпущен под одобренной [OSI](https://opensource.org/) "лицензией PostgreSQL". Он бесплатен, даже для использования в коммерческих продуктах. Смотрите [лицензию PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/).

Лицензия PostgreSQL (см. ссылку выше) очень короткая и, в общем-то, разрешает **всё** (использование, копирование, изменение, распространение ПО и документации) "за просто так", даже без явного письменного разрешения. Лишь при условии, что текст лицензии с копирайтами будет во всех копиях. Вот и все условия.

Установщик от EnterpriseDB не демонстрирует никакого лицензионного соглашения сам, и на сайте условий использования установщика я не наблюдаю. Но даже если она есть, это может быть лицензия лишь на установщик, но не на постгрес.

Comment: Установщик от EnterpriseDB содержит ПО от третьих лиц, которое распространяется по опенсорсной лицензии, значит ли это что если поставлять дистрибутив с коммерческим продуктом на одном компакт-диске, то необходимо, в случае чего, предоставить исходники коммерческого продукта?

Comment: @Fasta а где вы нашли хоть какое-то упоминание об обязанности предоставить исходники? Лицензия PostgreSQL этого не требует. Это вам не GPL :) Установщик EnterpriseDB их тоже не предоставляет.

Comment: В корневой папке установленного PostgreSQL есть текстовый документ `server_3rd_party_licenses`, где есть упоминание о библиотеках `gettext, libiconv`, которые распространяются под GPL. Это накладывает ограничения?

Comment: @Fasta поскольку вы никак их не меняли (чтобы к вам применялась обязанность публиковать исходники изменённой версии), то нужно указать факт использования продуктов под GPL, привести саму GPL и описать способ получения исходных кодов этих библиотек. В постгресе это должно быть уже сделано.

Comment: Давайте пройдемся еще раз. В корневой папке PostgreSQL указаны используемые сторонние библиотеки, наименования их лицензий и текст этих лицензий. Получается на меня не накладываются ограничения по использованию сервера PostgreSQL и я могу, указав copyright в каждой копии коммерческого продукта, делать с инсталлятором PostgreSQL от EnterpriseDB все что захочу и даже вставить его в свой собственный инсталлятор, например. И даже после этого нет никаких лазеек, чтобы затем понести юридическую ответственность за нарушение какой-либо из лицензий?

Comment: @Fasta Надо понимать, что я не юрист и не могу знать о наличии лазеек в самих лицензиях, так что если вы хотите знать точно, проконсультируйтесь у юриста. Я рассуждаю из того, что видел сам. Лицензия PostgreSQL не накладывает на вас каких-либо ограничений кроме необходимости поставлять текст лицензии вместе с каждой копией программного продукта. Но PostgreSQL сам содержит в себе стороннее ПО под другими лицензиями со своими требованиями. Эти требования должен соблюдать и установщик EnterpriseDB, и он их соблюдает. Дополнительных ограничений для коммерческих проектов GPL, AFAIK, не содержит.

Comment: Самое "страшное"/"драконовское" требование GPL -- это в случаях, когда ПО под GPL распространяется широкой общественности, публиковать исходный код всех изменений, которые в это ПО были внесены, грубо, чтобы ПО оставалось "общим". Поскольку вы сами изменений не вносили, то и публиковать вам ничего не нужно.

Comment: Благодарю за ценные комментарии. Вы помогли прояснить ситуацию :)

Comment: @Fasta Материал для дополнительного изучения: [GPL Violations](http://gpl-violations.org/).